# Rails: ActiveRecord query based on association value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have 2 models. `Report` and `Server` that have a belongs_to and has_many relationship. I created an accessor method using `delegate` that allows a `Report` to find its associated `Server.company_id`. Now, I want to run a query on `Report` that allows me to find all `Report` that are associated with a specific `Server` that has a specific `company_id` attribute of 5.

Here are my two models. And yes I know the current query wont work since `Report` does not have an attribute `company_id`.

And no, I dont want to store `company_id` inside of `Report` since that information doesn't belong in `Report`.

**Report**

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :server

 delegate :company_id, :to => :server

    class << self

        def method(url, base_url)
            #Report.where(company_id: 5)
        end
    end

end
```

**Server**

```
class Server < ActiveRecord::Base

 attr_accessible :company_id

 has_many :reports

end
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can perform a query like this:

```
Report.joins(:servers).where(:servers => {:company_id => 5})
```

To me, this is the cleaner solution to raw SQL.

Comment: You don't need `.all` on the end of this.

Comment: The second instance of "server", ".where(:server..." should be changed to ".where(:servers...".  It requires a plural form as it is name of the table.

Comment: Sometimes it happens that not all your records have an association relation in the database, e.b. in this case, not every report might `belong_to` a server. Using `.joins(:servers)` will in that case only return the reports that do `belong_to` a server. If you want to return all the reports no matter of their actual database relations to the servers, use `.includes(:servers)` instead. Downside: It's slightly slower (obviously).

Comment: Should this be used with any sort of `preload` or `include`, or is it performant like this?

Answer (score 49):

I'm using Rails 4.1.7 and the accepted answer did not work for me. What did work is

```
Report.joins(:server).where(:servers => {:company_id => 5})
```

*Note that the difference is the key in the where clause is pluralized (:servers instead of :server)*

Comment: Thanks. The same on Rails 4.2.5

Comment: same on Rails 5.1.6 :)

Comment: same on rails 6.0.0

Comment: This sadly did not work for me on Rails 6.

I get 

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column servers.company_id does not exist)`

Answer (score 27):

This should do the trick

```
Report.joins(:server).where('servers.company_id = ?', 5)
```

you could also add a scope for this like so

```
scope :with_company_id, lambda {|id| joins(:server).where('servers.company_id = ?', id) }
```

and then write

```
Report.with_company_id(5)
```

Comment: I think the 'server' in the `where` string should be plural.

Comment: Best answer since it also handles inequalities

Answer (score 0):

This maybe an overkill but we have [Arel](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Arel.html):

```rb
# Get the SQL

# arelise will return the SQL (string)
def arelise(company_id)
    # Tables to query
    reports = Report.arel_table # Main table
    servers = Server.arel_table.alias('servers')

    reports
        .join(servers, Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin).on(reports[:server_id].eq(servers[:id]))
        .where(servers[:company_id].eq(company_id))
        # Select all (*)
        .project(reports[Arel.star])
        .to_sql
end

sql = arelise(1)
# puts sql

# To Execute:

reports = Report.find_by_sql(sql)

# puts reports
```