# When to use singular vs plural form in activerecord queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm confused about singular vs plural forms in active record association queries.

Here are my two models:

```
class Biography < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :lifestyle, dependent: :destroy
end

class Lifestyle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :biography
end
```

And I've a search form, through which I'm finding lifestyles of a biography where diet is of a certain kind.

```
query = Biography
query = query.joins(:lifestyle).where(lifestyles:  { diet: params[:diet_ids] }) if params[:diet_ids]
result = query.all
```

I can understand why joins(:lifestyle) is singular because it is a one to one relationship.  But why is lifestyles in where(lifestyles...) plural? Is it because the table name is plural?  But I've seen examples on the web where it is not plural as in this link [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19489351/1801879)

Comment: It is plural because it is a table name as explained [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) (see `Joins` paragraph). IMO query in the answer in linked material doesn't work, answer below that one is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the link, makes sense.

Comment: Is there a better way to write the query posted above in question?

Comment: I'd do it the same way.