# Rails display similar products using tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a product model with tags using has_many :through association. I want to display similar products on the show page based on selected tags (tags are selected for each product).

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base    
    has_many :product_tags
    has_many :tags, through: :product_tags
end
```

Let's say I have 3 products and 2 tags - 'dog' and 'cat' (for dogs food and cats food).

Product 1 and 2 have their tags set to 'dog'. Product 3 has it's tag set to 'cat'.

So the desired output on Product 1 show page is that product 2 is displayed in the section "Items you might also find interesting". Product 3 should not be displayed there.

What is the correct approach in my controller?

My thoughts are right now using the & - operator, i.e.

```
(@product_1.product_tags & @product_2.product_tags).empty?
```

and if not empty, to display the product. But how do I accomplish this as a query in my controller?

This is my attempt

```
def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @similar_products = Product.where(!(tags & @product.tags).empty?)
  end
```

but it's obviously not working. How do I access the associated model in the query? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489017/rails-activerecord-query-based-on-association-value) solution as well, but it is not working for me:

```
Product.joins(:tags).where((:tags & @pr1.tags).empty?).all
NoMethodError: undefined method `&' for :tags:Symbol
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your ActiveRecord relations is that you're trying to use Ruby code in the `where` clause. It can cope with a simple hash or a SQL string, but nothing quite so complex as you're doing.

However, for the purpose you've mentioned above, I don't *think* you need a query for this; you can do it with Ruby arrays.

If your `Tag` model has the inverse relationship:

```
Class Tag
  has_many :product_tags
  has_many :products, through: :product_tags
end
```

... then you should be able to get your product's tags' products with this (at `map` it starts using a Ruby array rather than an ActiveRecord relation):

```
@similar_products = @product.tags.map(&:products).flatten.uniq - [@product]
```

Then you just need to iterate over `@similar_products` in the view to display them.

---

**If you *do* need a query** (e.g. if your data ends up taking a lot of time or memory to process), you'll want:

```
@similar_products = Product.joins(:tags).where('tags.id' => @product.tag_ids).where.not('products.id' => @product.id)
```

(Disclaimer, though: I haven't tested this.)

---

NB. **If your `ProductTag` model has no other logic on it,** you can dispense with `product_tag.rb` entirely, rename the table to `products_tags` (both parts plural and in alphabetical order), and use these instead:

```
class Product
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
class Tag
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

Comment: I think you've edited and added this part: `where.not('products.id' => @product.id)` This is actually super useful, I didn't thought of it :) I went with the query in the end, seems more "right" to me.