# Rails 5 joins filter associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I use a joins to query an associated model in rails 5? What I've tried is `DoctorLocation.joins(:location).where(:location => {:confidence => 2})` after looking at the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489017/rails-activerecord-query-based-on-association-value). What am I doing wrong? My query isn't returning any results.

```
pry(main)> DoctorLocation.joins(:locations).where(:locations => {:confidence => 2})
=> #<DoctorLocation::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3ff735a09d8c>

class DoctorLocation
   belongs_to :location

end

class Location
   has_many :doctor_locations, dependent: :destroy

end
```

Migration

```
   create_table :doctor_locations do |t|
      t.integer :doctor_profile_id
      t.integer :location_id
      t.text :uuid
      t.timestamps null: false
    end


 create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string   :address
      t.integer  :ordinal, :default => 1
      t.integer  :doctor_profile_id
      t.text     :uuid
      t.timestamps
    end

 add_column :locations, :confidence, :integer
```

Comment: Please share your migrations for ```doctor_locations``` and ```locations``` tables.
Also, what's wrong with your query? Does it return incorrect results?

Comment: @IlyaKonyukhov updated with output. The migrations are old and the tables have changed a bit. Anything specific you'd like to see?

Comment: I don't see a field named ```confidence``` in locations table, so your condition ```:location => {:confidence => 2}``` makes no sense here

Comment: @IlyaKonyukhov i added it in a later migration

Comment: If that integer field was eventually added to ```locations``` table later. My last suggestion is that location with ```confidence: 2``` is missing, that's why your request returns empty results.

Comment: i have locations with confidence 2. what's really strange is that no SQL is even generated and returning 0 results. It just returns the empty array

Comment: Does ```DoctorLocation.find_by_sql 'select doctor_locations.* from doctor_locations join locations on locations.id = doctor_locations.location_id where locations.confidence = 2'``` return any results (non-empty array)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181764/discussion-between-user2954587-and-ilya-konyukhov).

Comment: yep it returns results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have the right query. Rather its your testing method that is broken.

```
class DoctorLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  def self.with_confidence(c)
    DoctorLocation.joins(:location).where(locations: { confidence: c })
  end
end
```

This passing spec confirms that it works as expected:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe DoctorLocation, type: :model do

  after(:each) { DoctorLocation.destroy_all }
  it "includes locations with the correct confidence" do
    dl = DoctorLocation.create!(location: Location.create!(confidence: 2))
    DoctorLocation.create!(location: Location.create!(confidence: 1))
    expect(DoctorLocation.with_confidence(2)).to include dl
    expect(DoctorLocation.with_confidence(2).count).to eq 1
  end
  it "does not include rows without a match in the join table" do
    dl = DoctorLocation.create!(location: Location.create!(confidence: 1))
    expect(DoctorLocation.with_confidence(2)).to_not include dl
  end
end
```

Comment: You should probably start by checking that you actually have any records in the db that match the criteria.

Comment: that worked! but i don't get why it worked? what do you mean the testing method? can I not call it directly?

Comment: I mean that the problem was not really this code per say rather the circumstances surrounding it. Usually this boils down to not properly isolating the issue or not testing it properly - like just monkeying in the console instead of setting up real automated tests.

Comment: I figured out what the issue is - it's adding an `s` in the where clause.

Comment: `DoctorLocation.joins(:location).where(locations: { confidence: 2 })` works b/c there is a s in `.where(locations:`. Wow

Comment: I think you may actually have created an additional table named `location` by misstake. Otherwise that query should give an error `missing FROM-clause entry for table "location"`.

Answer (score 0):

In `joins` and `where` (hashed arguments) you need to declare name of association (`location`), not table name (`locations`):

```
DoctorLocation.joins(:location).where(location: { confidence: 2 })
```

It's often a source of confusion.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. It gives `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "location"`.

Comment: Take it easy. The problem was identified correctly, my mistake was that I propagated it to ```where``` as well.