# Rails: ActiveRecord query where all association is/is not a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Take [Rails: ActiveRecord query based on association value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489017/rails-activerecord-query-based-on-association-value) for example,

If we want to find reports with any related `servers`' `company_id` is `5`, we can write as
`Report.includes(:servers).where(servers: {company_id: 5})`

Given a report has multiple related servers, some server company_id is 5, some company_id is 6.

let's say,

- `report_a` has 2 servers, with company_id, 5,6 separately
- `report_b` has 2 servers, both with company_id, 5
- `report_c` has 2 servers, both with company_id, 6

How to find reports with all related servers's company_id is 5?(only all related servers's company_id is 5, then the report is qualified)

in the above case, the `report_b` is the answer

And find reports with all related servers's company_id is not 5?(only all related servers's company_id is Not 5, then the report is qualified)

in the above case, the `report_c` is the answer

Can I achieve by use `where` only?

Answer (score 1):

I'm very doubtful that it can be done using `where` ONLY. But your example also contains `includes` call, so I assume you meant "is it can be done using ActiveRecord methods, with as less raw SQL as possible". Well, it's achievable.

#### How to fetch reports having only servers with given company_id

It's a classical SELECT query with INNER JOIN between `reports` and `servers`. Since we need to look through all servers of a report, we GROUP reports by their id, and add HAVING to find `max` and `min` of `servers.company_id` for given report. The reports we're looking for have `max(company_id) == min(company_id) == 5`:

```
company_id = 5
Report.joins(:servers)
      .group('reports.id')
      .having("max(servers.company_id) = #{company_id} AND min(servers.company_id) = #{company_id}")
```

#### How to fetch only reports whose servers do not have given company_id

The best way to do so is to fetch those reports who do not match given condition (ie reports having servers with given `company_id`) and then exclude them. Thus we could fetch reports having servers with another company_ids, as well as reports without servers.

```
Report.where.not(
  id: Report.joins(:servers).where(servers: { company_id: 5 })
)
```

Comment: Your 2nd request does not need to be two separate queries! You can remove `pluck(:id)` (ActiveRecord will implicitly do `select(:id)` instead). That results in a single query.

Comment: I love the solution using GROUP BY and HAVING, I wouldn't have thought of that. I will keep that in mind for the future (although I would need to research and benchmark performance).

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed that ActiveRecord joins these 2 relations in a single SQL call. Thanks for pointing this out to me.

Answer (score 0):

### How to find reports with all related servers's company_id is 5?

This can be done by first finding the set of reports which have at least one server with company_id = 5. Then simply find the reports which are NOT in that set.

```
server_conditions = Server.where.not(company_id: 5)
  .or(Server.where(id: nil))  # Include reports which have NO servers.

reports_to_exclude = Report
  .left_joins(:servers)  # see notes about joins vs left_joins
  .merge(server_conditions)

Report.where.not(id: reports_to_exclude)  # ActiveRecord automatically selects `id` from reports_to_exclude, but it could be done explicitly, id: reports_to_exclude.select(:id)
```

#### joins vs left_joins

If there are reports records which have NO associated servers records then `joins` will yield a different result than `left_joins`. `left_joins` will *exclude* such reports while `joins` will *include* them.

It is up to you to determine which behavior is correct. If you know that you will never have a report which has no associated server, then either way will work (using `joins` is probably best, but you should always look at database-specific performance implications).

### find reports with all related servers's company_id is not 5?

The principle is the same here. First, find the set of reports which have a server with company_id of 5. Then select all the other reports which are not in that set.

```
reports_to_exclude = Report.joins(:servers).where(servers: { company_id: 5 })
Report.where.not(id: reports_to_exclude)
```

### Can I achieve by use where only?

This is as close as I can get you.