# Query on model associated as belongs_to in ActiveRecord (Is there a better way)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models

```
class InterestingGuest < ApplicationRecord
  # column_name
  # recommended_to
  # recommendee

  belongs_to :recommended_to, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recommendee, class_name: 'User'
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # column_name
  # membership_level : ['Member', 'Guest']

  has_many :guest_recommendations, class_name: 'InterestingGuest',
                                   foreign_key: 'recommended_to_id',
                                   dependent: :destroy

  has_many :recommendees, class_name: 'InterestingGuest',
                          foreign_key: 'recommendee_id',
                          dependent: :destroy
end
```

I'm trying to find all the `recommendees` where `membership_level` is `Guest`

the query I tried is

```
recommendees = InterestingGuest.where(recommended_to_id: user_id))
                               .pluck(:recommendee_id)
guests = User.where(id: recommendees).where(membership_level: 'Guest')
```

Even though it serves the purpose but is there a better way to achieve the same in a single query

Comment: You can try with this query, I created this query according to your post. `InterestingGuest.join("LEFT OUTER JOIN users on users.user_id = interesting_guests.recommendee_id where users.membership_level = 'Guest'")`

Comment: Hey @RohitLingayat thanks for the response but this will end up running the query on every `user` whereas I'm trying to find all the `recommendees` whose `membership_level` is guest and are `recommended_to` a specific user.

Comment: it will not execute the query for every user, it will execute only on matched users. There is left join on `users.user_id = interesting_guests.recommendee_id` and in the same way you can also add the `recommended_to` in where clause

Comment: Ahh Got it, thanks. this query works: `InterestingGuest.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN users on users.id = interesting_guests.recommendee_id where users.membership_level = 'Guest' and recommended_to_id = 1")`

Comment: (y) I am putting this comment as an answer. You can upvote if your problem is resolved by this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in this scenario.

Try:

```
InterestingGuest.join("LEFT OUTER JOIN users on users.user_id = interesting_guests.recommendee_id where users.membership_level = 'Guest'")
```

Here `user_id` means `recommendee_id` as per the association which you mentioned in the class.

Answer (score 0):

[Rails: ActiveRecord query based on association value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489017/rails-activerecord-query-based-on-association-value) should help you out.

Try:

```
InterestingGuest.joins(:users).where(users:{ membership_level: 'Guest' })
```

or

```
InterestingGuest.joins(:users).where('users.membership_level' = 'Guest')
```

Personaly I think the first looks neater.

Official docs:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: Thank you for the response, but joining `users` on `InterestingGuest` will not work since the association is via `recommended_to` and `recommendee`

Comment: Also, the query I'm trying here is to get `recommendees` whose `membership_level` is `guest` and are `recommended_to` a specific user