# How to design database tables for different types of Users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, types

I'm on a project with Rails, Postgresql and Active Record, where I have Users, that can be either Influencers, or Creators.

The Users have common columns such as `email`, `password`, `first_name` and `last_name`, but :

- influencers will have `followers`, `eg_rate`, `account` columns
- creators will have `SIRET_number` and `specialty` columns

How can I design my database so Influencers and Creators are kind of "child" of the Users table ? I mean, is it possible to have a db where I can access a User' followers or a User's specialty with one query, or I'll always have to do multiple queries to achieve this ? I've tried to create three tables for each, with a foreign key `user_id` in Influencers table and Creators table. I also tried to add a `user_type` column to my User table where I pass the values of either "influencer" or "creator", but I'm kind of lost on how to link every tables...

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is right.

You can create a table `users` with the common columns and add a foreign key to `influencers` and `creators` tables.

Then when you need to retrieve the data, you can use ActiveRecord relations to easily fetch data and use ActiveRecord's [includes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) method for relations.

For example:

```rb
class Creator < ActiveRecord::Base
   # The relation must be set
   has_one :user
end

# To fetch data anywhere else:
Creator.find_by(SIRET_number: 1234).includes(:user)
```

If you need to retrieve a creator or influencer by an attribute from related users table, you can use [joins](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins):

```rb
Creator.joins(:users).where(users: {email: "foo@bar.com"})
```

Make sure you have the relations set in both User and Creator models.
Check out [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489017/rails-activerecord-query-based-on-association-value) for more info.

By using includes or joins instead of using `creator.user` you'll avoiding the unnecessary additional query. The downside is the syntax is now longer, you can maybe create your own getters to easily retrieve data instead of writing "includes" everytime.

Also assuming you're not aware of this method, I suggest you to read about the common N+1 problem with Rails & ActiveRecord. The same methods can solve a lot of problems for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The problem  I get with that AR relation is `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column creators.email does not exist)`. What do you mean by  "add a foreign key to it from `influencers`and `creators`table" ? Isn't it the contrary ? I mean, it's in my Influencers and Creators table that I have a `user_id` foreign_key column. Not sure to properly understand your advice.

Comment: By "add a foreign key" I meant your current user_id columns which you already created, it's already set.

Comment: The problem with email is that email is a column in users table, not creators so you cannot use that attribute in a creators query.