# Rails: ActiveRecord query based on attribute of associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I've got an Organization model and User model. Organization belongs to User with :creator alias:

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User', optional: true
end
```

User model is based upon devise with confirmation by email required. It has .confirm? method which returns boolean value.

So I want to filter all organizations with creators who have confirmed accounts. But when I try something like this:

```
Organization.find_by(creator: creator.confirmed?)
```

I get this error:

> NameError (undefined local variable or method `creator' for
> main:Object)

How can I filter Organizations based on attributes of its creators?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails: ActiveRecord query based on association value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489017/rails-activerecord-query-based-on-association-value)

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of devise confirmable module, the method [`confirm?`](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L106) will return true if the column `confirmed_at` is set to not null.

```
  # Verifies whether a user is confirmed or not
  def confirmed?
    !!confirmed_at
  end
```

So, You can get the confirmed users by querying the users with `confirmed_at` is not null:

Try the below to get the organization created by unconfirmed users:

```
Organization.joins(:creator).where('users.confirmed_at IS NOT NULL')
```