# Is it possible to call model method in where clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models

```
class Project
   has_one: user
end

class User
   # Attributes
   # active: Boolean
   # under_18: Boolean

   def can_work?
     active? && under_18 == false
   end
end
```

The logic for `can_work?`

> if active is true and under_18 is false then they can work

I want to do something like this but it's not possible

```
Project.all.joins(:user).where('users.can_work? = ?', false)
```

Essentially what I'm looking for is to find all users who `can't work`

I know I can use Scope, but copying the logic that I specified above in scope is confusing.

Here's the scenario that I'm looking for

```
active |  under_18
------------------
   T        T        = F
   T        F        = T
   F        T        = F
   F        F        = F
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't use model methods like that, no. Only database attributes.

Comment: You can create a scope for this and it does not seem confusing to me. `scope can_work, -> {where(active: true, under_18: false)}` assuming those are the columns. If you just store age then `scope can_work, -> {where(active: true).where(arel_attribute(:age).gteq(18))}` will do the trick

Comment: @engineersmnky Using scope is possible - `scope can_work, -> {where(active: true, under_18: false)}`, How do I negate `can_work`? if you look at the table above negating `can_work` can be confusing but that's the requirement

Comment: @engineersmnky hence why i decided to go for this route `where('users.can_work? = ?', false)` but according to Sergio it is not possible :(

Comment: @airsoftFreak: try this then: `User.where.not(User.can_work.where_values_hash)`

Comment: Or you could inline the scope to gain readability if you don't need it elsewhere: `User.where.not(active: true, under_18: false)`

Comment: I think you are mistaken. This worked for me.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the answer, unfortunately `User.where.not(active: true, under_18: false)` will just negate the `active` and `under_18` I'm trying to achieve what the table above is doing.

Comment: Example if `active: true and under_18: false  ----->  active: false and under_18: true`

Comment: I see. The AND should become an OR in the negated expression. Well, you can always write it out explicitly. `scope :cant_work, -> { where("not active or under_18")}` or a variant of this (using arel_table/arel_attribute, for example)

Comment: Thanks but `scope :cant_work, -> { where("not active or under_18")}` this logic still is not helping. I'm not sure how to do the exact logic as in the table above. Appreciate your help anyways.

Comment: Seems simple enough to go with `User.where.not(id: User.can_work.select(:id))`

Comment: @airsoftFreak: wait a second, that truthiness table describes "can_work", not the "cant_work".

Comment: Untested and just writing by hand but `scope :can_work, ->(t=true) {where(Arel::Grouping.new(arel_attribute(:active).eq(true).and(arel_attribute(:under_18).eq(false))).eq(t))}` should work. This will allow for `User.can_work` for users that can work and `User.can_work(false)` for users that can't work.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev After further testing, I can confirm that your code snippet was working on my side. I'm really grateful for your time to help me with this. `scope :cant_work, -> { where("not active or under_18")}`

Comment: @engineersmnky Your code snippet is working as well, I'm really grateful for your help as well. I used a combination of your code and Sergio to prevent ambiguous error if I just do it this way `.merge(User.cant_work)` instead I use your snippet `.merge(User.where(id: User.cant_work.select(:id)))`

Comment: @engineersmnky I haven't tested this code yet `scope :can_work, ->(t=true) {where(Arel::Grouping.new(arel_attribute(:active).eq(true).and(arel_attribute(:under_18).eq(false))).eq(t))}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both of your help, you guys really help me, really appreciate it. i will create a bounty tomorrow and split the points since both of you did help me. Thanks guys. The final code that I use is `.merge(User.where(id: User.cant_work.select(:id)))`

Comment: @airsoftFreak: note that this last version performs two DB queries and is potentially slow (if `cant_work` returns thousands or tens of thousands users)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if you are referring to `User.where(id: User.cant_work.select(:id))` this will only preform 1 query technically speaking because the where will be converted to "NOT IN( sub query)" which is far more performant than "NOT IN(list of ids)" but yes a true inversion of conditions will be more performant but string SQL makes it more difficult to recognize and change in the future. Overall the sub query will likely result in very reasonable response times since id is a primary key and unique indexed by default.

Comment: @engineersmnky: ah, I thought that `select` was a `pluck`. My bad. You're right, of course.

Comment: Started a bounty thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

As per [Sergio Tulentsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125816/sergio-tulentsev)'s answer, you can't do it. But if you want it DRY so badly you can use scopes.

Scope definition alt. 1:

```
scope :can_work, -> { where active: true, under_18: false }
scope :cant_work, -> { where.not id: User.can_work.pluck(:id) }
```

Scope definition alt. 2:

```
scope :can_work, ->(t=true) { where(active: t).where.not(under_18: t) }
```

New can_work? method

```
def can_work?
  User.can_work.pluck(:id).include?(id)
end
```

Now you can call:

```
Project.joins(:user).merge(User.cant_work)
```

Or

```
Project.joins(:user).merge(User.can_work(false))
```

PS. Good luck with the speed.

Comment: I agree with this, convention as opposed to configuration.

Comment: using a scope is the best way available and recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```rb
Project.joins(:users).where(user: {under_18: <Bool>, active: <Bool>})
```

Insert the `Boolean` values (`true` or `false`) that you want in place of `<Bool>`s above.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19489351/7974948)

---

##### Side note

If `users` are workers then I suggest changing names in your schema to look like:

`workers`

| id | project_id | under_18 | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | TRUE | TRUE |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

`projects`

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "lorem" |
| ... | ... |

So the associations would be

```
class Project
   has_one :worker
end

class Worker
   belongs_to :project
end
```

And the query would then look like

```
Project.joins(:workers).where(worker: {under_18: <Bool>, active: <Bool>})
```

I think it makes more sense from a naming standpoint.

That is since `users` are oftentimes regarded as the owners in association relationships (i.e. a project would *belong to* a user, and a user would *have many* projects). Just a quick side suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer: Scope**

Scopes are custom queries defined in Rails model inside method named `scope`

A scope can have two parameters, the name of the scope and lambda which contains the query.

Something like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  scope :is_active, -> { where(active: true) }

  scope :under_18, -> { where(under_18: true) }

end
```

Scope returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. So scopes can be chained with multiple scopes like,

```
User.is_active.under_18
```

The scope is nothing but a method same as class methods. The only difference is that you get a guarantee of getting `ActiveRecord::Relation` as an output of scope. This helps you to write specific code and helps to reduce errors in the code.

**Default Scope**:
You can also add a default scope on any model which is implicitly applied to every query made on the respective model.
Be cautious while using this though as this might cause unpredictable results.

For example:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  default_scope :is_active, -> { where(active: true) }

  scope :under_18, -> { where(under_18: true) }

end
```

In the above case, `User.first` will return the first user who is active.

**Benefits of Scope**

1. Testable - The separate scopes are more testable now as they now follow the Single Responsibility Principle
2. Readable
3. DRY - Combining multiple scopes allows you not to repeat the code